# Trouble understanding the syntax and parameters of ListDeconvolve

Tags: convolution

I'd like to use the `ListDeconvolve` command to do the following task but I'm having a hard time understanding the description in the Wolfram Language Reference.

Suppose my original expression was like this:

```
ListConvolve[{1,-2,1},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7},{1,-1},0]
```

The output sequence then is:

```
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -8, 7}
```

Now I'd like to do the **opposite thing** – i.e. I would imagine to have 3 input parameters. One would be my input sequence, which in this case is `{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -8, 7}`. Another input parameter would be the kernel sequence, which in this case is `{1, -2, 1}`.
The third parameter would be the length of my output sequence. For example, if I set the length to be 7, then the output sequence would be `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`.

How can I do that?

Comment: According to the documentation the third parameter of `ListDeconvolve` is a `Method` and not any parameter. It is, also, well-documented that it is only an **approximate** inverse of `ListConvolve`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this might be quite difficult in general. In the special case where the convolution had full overhangs on each side it is equivalent to polynomial multiplication, and can thus be undone by polynomial division.

Your example is done like so.

```
lc = ListConvolve[{1, -2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, -1}, 0];
ker = {1, -2, 1};
quot = PolynomialQuotient[lc . x^Range[0, Length[lc] - 1], 
   ker . x^Range[0, Length[ker] - 1], x];
CoefficientList[quot, x]

(* Out[1858]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} *)
```

In other cases it might be possible to set up a system of linear equations to find the deconvolved list. Maybe.

--- edit ---

There are situations in which we may have sufficient data to reconstruct the missing list. Say for example we know that the third argument is `{1,1}` and the fourth is 0. We will apply this to the running example.

Set up the example. The `lcm2` intended as "list convolution minus two elements".

```
ker = {1, -2, 1};
lcm2 = ListConvolve[{1, -2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 1}, 0]

(* Out[1912]= {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Now create a list of variables to convolve with the kernel. Convolve using the parameter settings we have assumed above.

```
dcoeffs = Array[c, Length[lcm2]];
convol = ListConvolve[ker, dcoeffs, {1, 1}, 0]

(* Out[1914]= {c[1], -2 c[1] + c[2], c[1] - 2 c[2] + c[3], 
 c[2] - 2 c[3] + c[4], c[3] - 2 c[4] + c[5], c[4] -
 2 c[5] + c[6], c[5] - 2 c[6] + c[7]} *)
```

Equate this partial-overhang convolution to `lcm2` and solve for the second list.

```
dcoeffs /. Solve[convol == lcm2][[1]]

(* Out[1910]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} *)
```

I do not know how far we can go toward relaxing our assumptions. I have actually worked on a related problem several years back. The quality and usefulness of my results I can only describe as hysterically lame.

http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/talks/issues-blind-deconvolution-computer-algebra-tale-dark-side

--- end edit ---

Comment: Thanks for this.
Could a similar procedure be used in the cases where I want to truncate a sequence that would otherwise be infinite? For example, if my initial input sequence were {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} without the final {-8, 7}, then the resulting output sequence would go forever. However, if I said that I only wanted to know the first 7 items, I would again get {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}.

Comment: See edit. It can be done in restricted circumstances. I do not know the full necessary or sufficient conditions but I'll illustrate based on this example.